# Can $\mu(A) < \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mu (A_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} $
  be a sequence of sets that Lebesgue measurable on $\mathbb{R}$
  such that $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)<\infty$
  for all $n$
  (integer). Let

$$A={ \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}}{ \left(\bigcap_{k\geq m}^{\infty}A_{k}\right)}$$

Do we have the following inequality:

$$ \mu(A) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) ?$$

And can

$$\mu(A) < \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)?$$

My question is the second inequality (the first is well-known).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't use `$$ .. $$` in the title of your questions. It messes up the front page.

Comment: Okay I see. I'm sorry.

Comment: Further TeX tips: Use `\liminf` and do not overuse `\left .. \right`. Most of the time they're unnecessary and sometimes they make things look wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is the set of points which are in infinitely many of the $A_k$. This gives us an idea: Make $A$ very small, but keep the $A_k$ at a fixed size.

In particular we can take

$\displaystyle\qquad
A_k = \begin{cases}
  [0,1] & k \text{ odd} \cr
  [1,2]  & k \text{ even}
\end{cases}$

Now $A = \{1\}$ and $\mu(A_k) = 1$ for all $k$ giving us the desired sharp inequality.

You can make all kinds of variations on this theme. For example $A_k = [k,k+1]$.